# Help to understand how work this halogen lamp power supply

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inverter, analysis, schmitt-trigger

I ask for your help for the following:

1. Understanding how this power supply works (how the 18kHz are generated).
2. The role of 100Hz.
3. How thermal and overload protection works.
4. How those protection are preserved in the version b (with the omitted Q3).
5. The role of inverters #3 and #6.
6. Why they use a PNP and not a NPN for Q5.
7. Why they use this unusual connection for the transformerless power supply (R16 thru C11).

I made a schematic by reverse engineering; diagram and other photos are below.
[image]

Comment: You said: *why this unusual connection for the transformerless power supply* <-- it has a transformer so what do you really mean?

Comment: it's connected between middle point of c3-c4 and Q1-Q2 and not directly in the input of the power supply

Comment: Have you tried to simulate the circuit? Especially please try PNP instead of NPN on Q5.

Comment: no, I apologize, i don't have skills in simulation

Comment: The voltage at c3 c4 is half the DC rail. The transformer will see a bipolar signal from the transistors. It’s a reasonably common technique. Note that it is not a flyback converter.

Comment: @Kartman, Note that it is not a flyback converter, 
What is the type of the converter?

Comment: That schematic is *awful*. Why would they write the component values that way?!

Comment: @Hearth , Why would they write the component values that way? this is SMD resistor code directly transposed in to the schematic

Comment: @maher471 Yes, I worked that out eventually. It's a terrible way to write it because it makes the schematic hard to read, and not all SMD parts will use that code. A lot of them use the even more difficult-to-read EIA-96 code.

Comment: @Hearth I concur. The reverse engineered schematic should have already decoded values near designators. This is helpful also for the OP when looking again at the schematic: they wouldn't need to redecode the parts in their mind every time. The undecoded values could be useful backreference to the photos/real circuit, but they should be put in brackets and maybe in another color. Moreover, decoded values are also helpful when checking the real circuit with a DMM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no time to provide a complete analysis of the circuit. I'll discuss some key points.

The general structure of this circuit is that of an *inverter*, i.e. a DC/AC converter. In particular this is a [half-bridge inverter](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/designtopologies/half-bridge-inverter) topology, whose load must be connected between the junction of Q1 and Q2 and the junction between C4 and C3.

Here is an example of a half-bridge *converter* used to convert DC to DC. Just remove the rectifiers from the transformer secondary and you get an half-bridge *inverter* (DC/AC converter).

[image]

(Source: [Power Topologies Handbook, Texas Instruments - TI document code: SLYU036](https://www.ti.com/seclit/ug/slyu036/slyu036.pdf))

In your case the load is actually two loads in parallel, the first part of the load is the primary of the transformer, which will produce the AC needed to drive the halogen bulb at its secondary (12V AC out in your schematic).

The other load is comprised by C11, D3, D4, D5 and R16. This is essentially a simple AC/DC linear converter with Zener regulation, i.e. it is a power supply circuit. It is used to generate the 13V DC needed to power the other low-voltage blocks in the circuit.

In particular, C11 is used as a capacitive dropper (it's a cheap way to drop a big AC voltage without wasting power in a power resistor), D4 is an half-wave rectifier, whereas D3 is used so that C11 sees the full AC cycle. D5 + R16 are just a Zener regulator, with C1 acting as an output filter capacitor.

R1+R2 are used to power the Zener regulator through C5 when the circuit powers up, allowing to power the 13V line before the converter starts switching and allowing the converter to start-up.

The oscillation is generated by positive feedback from the additional transformer winding which is connected to the gate of Q1 through R4||(R5+C9).

R15 in parallel with R14 (~2Ω total) are used as a current-sense resistor for the power MOSFETS (for Q2 in particular). If the current through Q2 raises too much so that D7 conducts (0.6V/2Ω≈0.3A), then Q3 will turn on and block the converter, acting as an overload protection circuit (this value is coherent with the "max 0.23A primary current" shown on the device case.

R11 is a pull-down for Q3 gate and C14+C15+R12+R11b are just a filter to extract the peak value of the current through the current-sense resistor.

If Q3 turns on, it will short to ground the input of inverter #2, thus forcing its output high. This in turn will bring the node marked "18kHz" high trough D2, thus inhibiting the switching of Q4 and thus of Q1. In particular, Q4 base will go high and Q4 will short the gate of Q1 to its source, making Q1 to turn off.

At the same time, an high level on inverter #2 output will also reach the input of inverter #1, forcing its output low. This will turn on PNP BJT Q5, that will in turn short the gate of Q2 to its source, making also Q2 to turn OFF.

Therefore, in the end, when an overcurrent is detected, both power MOSFETs Q1 and Q2 will turn off.

About Q5: it is used to turn off Q2 quickly. In fact Q2 is turned on when the output of inverter #1 is high and Q2's gate capacitance is charged through R13. In this case Q5 is turned off. When Q1 is on its gate capacitance is charged to 13V and it is that voltage that is applied to Q5 when output of #1 becomes low. D6 is there to protect the base-collector junction of Q5 when it is reverse biased by those 13V (a small signal BJT BC junction max voltage is around 5-6V).

About Q3: without it there is no way the current sensed by R14||R15 can influence the switching behavior, so (unless there are other connections/components you missed) *version B has no overcurrent protection*.

**EDIT** (after a clarification from the OP about his question)

Inverter #3 and #6 form a latch, i.e. a circuit that will hold a stable logic state (either high or low) once put in that state.

I suspect that D8, which is reverse-biased from the 13V line through R7, may act as a temperature sensor (it's reverse leakage current depends exponentially on its temperature - it doubles for every 10°C increase).

This may be used to change the state of the latch, which in turn may change the voltage on inverter #2 input, which is a full-wave rectified 100Hz sinusoidal voltage (through R1+R2) superimposed with a DC value set by the output of #3 (13V when high, 0V when low) through R10.

It would take some calculations to get the exact resulting voltage waveform at #2 input and how it could affect the 18kHz oscillation (and whether it could stop the oscillator in case of overtemperature).

Comment: thanks very much Mr Lorenzo it's very detailed, Just there remains a question about the rule of inverter #3 and #6, .
thats all, and thanks in advance